# How can i change some string values to numeric values on data imported from Excel in matlab

Tags: matlab

I'm dealing with NSL-KDD data set and i want to change some strings to numeric values using matlab and here's my code

```
a = xlsread ('20 Percent Training Set.xls'); % normal data
[n,p]= size (a);
% calculate mean for normal data
for z =1:n
    for v=1:p
        b = a(z,v);
        if strcmp(b,'tcp')
            b=1;
        end
    end
end
a
```

but when i print the matrix `a` the NaN values still unchanged, is there something i can do, thanks.

Comment: ?!?! which Nan values? are you not converting string to numeric?

Comment: @AnderBiguri tcp values appear in the output as NaN without changing to 1

Comment: So.... if they are NaN, they are not `tcp`, right? `b` will not have `tcp`. You can replace your entire code by `a(isnan(a))=1`;

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are changing `b`, not `a`. You need to set `a(z,v)=1`. Therefore, your code should be:

```
a = xlsread ('20 Percent Training Set.xls'); % normal data
[n,p]= size (a);
% calculate mean for normal data
for z =1:n
    for v=1:p
        b = a(z,v);
        if strcmp(b,'tcp')
            a(z,v)=1;
        end
    end
end
a
```

Comment: still OP is mixing up 'tcp' and NaN

Comment: It would be easier to find the correct solution if the file (or an equivalent matrix) was provided.

Comment: @ziadx123: see above

Comment: @Zarauztarra thanks for your response sir but nothing happened i'm still getting NaN instead of one

Comment: Can you share the 'xls' file so that I can test it? (e.g. at  [Expirebox](https://expirebox.com/)) @ziadx123

Comment: There you share a .csv file. I cannot see the problem you get if you don't provide me the 'xls' file you are working with, as it might be an error of csv-xls conversion rather than matlab coding. @ziadx123